# list videos android, code error

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

I try to make a list of all the movies from sdcard. Everything was fine, but the application stops. I can not find error in the log.
the idea is to have a list of local movies, but fail to make it work.
Please help! 
thank you very much

Code:

```
public class main extends Activity {
//set constants for MediaStore to query, and show videos
private final static Uri MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
private final static String _ID = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
private final static String MEDIA_DATA = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
//flag for which one is used for images selection
private GridView _gallery;
private Cursor _cursor;
private int _columnIndex;
private int[] _videosId;
private Uri _contentUri;
String filename;
int flag = 0;



protected Context _context;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _context = getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //set GridView for gallery
    _gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.videoGrdVw);
    //set default as external/sdcard uri
    _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    initVideosId();

    //set gallery adapter
    setGalleryAdapter();


}
private void setGalleryAdapter() {
    _gallery.setAdapter(new VideoGalleryAdapter(_context));
    _gallery.setOnItemClickListener(_itemClickLis);
    flag = 1;
}
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener _itemClickLis = new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused", "rawtypes" })
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        // Now we want to actually get the data location of the file
        String [] proj={MEDIA_DATA};
        // We request our cursor again
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                MEDIA_DATA + " like ? ",       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                new String[] {"%Movies%"},       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        // We want to get the column index for the data uri
        int count = _cursor.getCount();
        //
        _cursor.moveToFirst();
        //
        _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(MEDIA_DATA);
        // Lets move to the selected item in the cursor
        _cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        // And here we get the filename
        filename = _cursor.getString(_columnIndex);
        //*********** You can do anything when you know the file path :-)
        showToast(filename);

        Intent i = new Intent(main.this, Player.class);
        i.putExtra("videoPath", filename);
        startActivity(i);


        //
    }
};
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void initVideosId() {
    try
    {
        //Here we set up a string array of the thumbnail ID column we want to get back
        String [] proj={_ID};
        // Now we create the cursor pointing to the external thumbnail store
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                MEDIA_DATA + " like ? ",       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                new String[] {"%Movies%"},       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        int count= _cursor.getCount();
        // We now get the column index of the thumbnail id
        _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
        //initialize
        _videosId = new int[count];
        //move position to first element
        _cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            int id = _cursor.getInt(_columnIndex);
            //
            _videosId[i]= id;
            //
            _cursor.moveToNext();
            //
        }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        showToast(ex.getMessage().toString());
    }

}
protected void showToast(String msg)
{
    Toast.makeText(_context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//
private class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context c)
    {
        _context = c;
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return _videosId.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(_context);;
        try
        {
            if(convertView!=null)
            {
                imgVw= (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imgVw.setImageBitmap(getImage(_videosId[position]));
            imgVw.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
            imgVw.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("main:getView()-135: ex " + ex.getClass() +", "+ ex.getMessage());
        }
        return imgVw;
    }

    // Create the thumbnail on the fly
    private Bitmap getImage(int id) {
        Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getContentResolver(),
                id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        return thumb;
    }

}
```

Log:

```
> > 01-30 14:08:32.241 11542-11542/ro.vrt.main I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11542 SIG: 9 01-30 14:08:37.508 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main
> W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
> /data/app/ro.vrt.main-2/lib/x86 01-30 14:08:37.510
> 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/fd: BootstrapApplication created. Android
> package is ro.vrt.main, real application class is null. 01-30
> 14:08:37.511 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/fd: Resource override is
> /data/data/ro.vrt.main/files/studio-fd/right/resources.ap_ 01-30
> 14:08:37.511 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/fd: Resource patch last
> modified: 1454178687000 01-30 14:08:37.511 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main
> I/fd: APK last modified: 1454178303000 < resource patch 01-30
> 14:08:37.512 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/fd: Last code patch:
> /data/data/ro.vrt.main/files/studio-fd/dex/slice_7_2c7a21c06f0b2310eadc38962f037e8d9bfeb1d7-classes.dex
> 01-30 14:08:37.512 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/fd: APK last modified:
> 1454178303000 < 1454178752000 code patch 01-30 14:08:37.512
> 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/fd: Bootstrapping class loader with dex list
> [/data/data/ro.vrt.main/files/studio-fd/dex/slice_7_2c7a21c06f0b2310eadc38962f037e8d9bfeb1d7-classes.dex,
> /data/data/ro.vrt.main/files/studio-fd/dex/slice_5_19eb0e3297ec4866c77c2a0621402c73a2c55731-classes.dex,
> /data/data/ro.vrt.main/files/studio-fd/dex/slice_3_c9e402f5905d7d75403d2e682e8e8f0378a74371-classes.dex]
> 01-30 14:08:37.512 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/fd: Incremental dex path
> is
> /data/data/ro.vrt.main/files/studio-fd/dex/slice_7_2c7a21c06f0b2310eadc38962f037e8d9bfeb1d7-classes.dex:/data/data/ro.vrt.main/files/studio-fd/dex/slice_5_19eb0e3297ec4866c77c2a0621402c73a2c55731-classes.dex:/data/data/ro.vrt.main/files/studio-fd/dex/slice_3_c9e402f5905d7d75403d2e682e8e8f0378a74371-classes.dex
> 01-30 14:08:37.525 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main W/System: ClassLoader
> referenced unknown path: /data/data/ro.vrt.main/files/studio-fd/lib
> 01-30 14:08:37.529 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/fd: Starting server
> socket listening for package ro.vrt.main on
> android.net.LocalSocketAddress@7d592ee 01-30 14:08:37.533
> 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/fd: Started server for package ro.vrt.main
> 01-30 14:08:37.692 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
> down VM
>                                                              
>                                                              
>                                                              --------- beginning of crash 01-30 14:08:37.692 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                              Process: ro.vrt.main, PID: 11671
>                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{ro.vrt.main/ro.vrt.main.main}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null
> array
>                                                                  at ro.vrt.main.main$VideoGalleryAdapter.getCount(main.java:142)
>                                                                  at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:206)
>                                                                  at ro.vrt.main.main.setGalleryAdapter(main.java:56)
>                                                                  at ro.vrt.main.main.onCreate(main.java:51)
>                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)  01-30
> 14:08:44.290 11671-11671/ro.vrt.main I/Process: Sending signal. PID:
> 11671 SIG: 9 01-30 14:09:23.786 11878-11878/ro.vrt.main I/Process:
> Sending signal. PID: 11878 SIG: 9
```

and main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/videoGrdVw"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dip"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are assigning the adapter to your listview at that time `_videosId` is null because database query is not complete by then. You need to set your adapter once data is ready.

Because you don't know the size of array in advance; you can't even initialize the array with blank data.

**Solution**

Remove `setGalleryAdapter();` from method `onCreate`

And

Put `setGalleryAdapter();` after the `for` loop in method `initVideosId()`

Comment: do not receive the error, but does not display the list. as though it did not find the movie sdcard

Comment: @diaconuliviu: Well that is a totally different matter. Probably you should post a different question for that.